# Asymmetric encryption with attr_encryption

Tags: ruby, encryption

We're using the Gem: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted as a way to encrypt some of our fields in our Rails application database.

Because we don't want the data to be accessible (even to developers) who don't know the key we have looked into using the Gem to do proper asymmetric encryption whereby the key is with the user itself and would require their password in order to decrypt certain fields.

For example:

`attr_encrypted :example_field, key: proc { |user| user.key }`

However I have two questions:

1.) How would we make sure the key itself had to be decrypted on user login? As the current implementation just means we have only made a key per user and moved it into the database and instead of an environment variable.

2.) According to the rules of asymmetric encryption we'd use a public key to encrypt the data and then the private (user key) to decrypt the data... but haven't been able to see how this Gem would support this as seems to only care about a single key for an attribute rather than proper public/private keys.

Comment: Keep in mind to truly prevent access by developers the developers must not have access to the key or what's used to generate the key, like a user password, something that *could* be obtained if they have access to the production system.